# Why does codeStar Notifications does not send notification to SNS Topic encrypted with default aws managed key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sns, aws-codepipeline, amazon-kms

I am trying to send codepipeline notifications to SNS Topic using CodeStar notifications.

The SNS Topic is encrypted using aws managed key and not customer managed key.

SNS Topic access policy allows codestar to send notifications to it.

The default policy for the sns key( default alias/aws/sns) is as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "auto-sns-1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow access through SNS for all principals in the account that are authorized to use SNS",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:CreateGrant",
                "kms:ListGrants",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "kms:CallerAccount": "xxxxxxxx",
                    "kms:ViaService": "sns.xxxx.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow direct access to key metadata to the account",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Describe*",
                "kms:Get*",
                "kms:List*",
                "kms:RevokeGrant"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

other aws entities like other iam role ( role for manual approval notification ) is able to send the notifications to this topic. if I remove encryption then even codestar is also able to send notifications

I have seen this aws doc -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dtconsole/latest/userguide/set-up-sns.html which talks about policy for aencrypted sns. in the default policy principal is set to all aws identities which should allow codestar to handle encryption and decryption

```
"Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
```

Is there a caveat that codestar cannot send notifications to sns topics which are encrypted using aws managed key?